# how to sum each column in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I'm trying to sum all the columns from a table but its not working.
This is my query to the DB:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(clicks) as total FROM urls WHERE member_id='$mem_id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$sum = $row['total'];
```

When I try to run the script nothing is working. I tried also with while loop and I get all the results from column clicks on a new line and I cannot sum them.
Where I am doing a mistake ?

Comment: Everywhere. Grab yourself any basic book or tutorial on using PHP and MySQL published in the last 3 years.

Comment: "nothing is working" What does that mean? White page? a lot of warnings? Fatal error? How about using the mysqli functions (note the i) as mysql_query cs. has been deprecated for a long time and are non exsitsing in current php versions. And else: do some cheching on "did my query fail, and if so: what was according to mysql the error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
mysqli_ functions are better.

$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname.':'.$mysql_port, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

$query = "SELECT SUM(clicks) as total FROM urls WHERE member_id='$mem_id'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$sum = $row["total"];

Comment: Thank you, the mysqli function helped me. Problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

use following Query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM urls WHERE member_id='$mem_id'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);

$totalclicks= 0;
while ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query_run)) {
    $totalclicks += $num['clicks'];
}
echo $totalclicks;
```